# I have this code that works in JSFiddle but not on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create a new button every time the post button is clicked and each new button should have its own counter. This works in JSFiddle but not when I use it.

```js
 $(function() {
   $('.input_button').on('click', function() {
     text = $('.input_text').val();
     var btn = $("<button></button>");
     btn.text("Like!");
     $("body").append(btn);
     btn.after("<span class='clicks'></span>")
     var clicks = 0;
     btn.click(function() {
       clicks++;
       $(this).next(".clicks").html(clicks);
     });
     if (text != undefined) {
       post = '<div class="post test--post">' + '<img src="photo.JPG" width="20" height="25" alt=""/>' + '<p><span>jaleelg: </span></p>' + text +
         '<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>' + "<br>" + Date() + " " + '</div>';
       new_post = $('.post_feed').append($(post))
       new_post = $('.post_feed').append($(btn))
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h3 id="feed">My Posts</h3>
  <section class="post_feed test--post_feed">
  </section>
</section>


<input class="input_text test--input_text" type="text">
<button type="submit" class="input_button test--input_button">Post</button>
<div id="clicks">

</div>
```

Comment: Are you referencing jQuery prior to your jQuery-related script content?

Comment: Works fine. Check your browser console for meaningful errors. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgyZoE

Comment: `This works in JSFiddle but not when I use it` - debugging 101 - what's in the developer tools console

Comment: @MichaelCoker I clicked your link but I see the same result. Each like button should have it's own counter but it remains at 0

Comment: @RionWilliams yes and i tried moving it, no difference.

Comment: @tanqNting is ths what you're trying to do? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/PWyNZy

Comment: @tanqNting, I thought I already answered this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in this:

```
btn.click(function() {
       clicks++;
       $(this).next(".clicks").html(clicks);
     });
```

Like this:

```
btn.click(function() {
$('.clicks').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });       
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

This pen works:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygRxOq?editors=0010

```
$(function() {

  $("body").on("click",".like",function(e) {
    clicks = $(e.target.parentElement).find("#clicks").text() / 1 + 1;
    $(e.target.parentElement).find("#clicks").text(clicks);
  });

  $('.input_button').on('click', function() {
    text = $('.input_text').val();
    post = '<div class="post test--post">' + 
               '<img src="photo.JPG" width="20" height="25" alt=""/>' + 
               '<p><span>jaleelg: </span></p>' + text + 
               '<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>' + 
               '<br>' + Date() + '<br>'+
               '<button class="like">Like!</button>'+
           '</div>';

    new_post = $('.post_feed').append($(post));
  });

});
```

Comment: `$("body").on("action","selector", function(){});` is used to add events to element's before they're created ... the event is attached to the parent (body)

Comment: Once the "like" button is pressed i get his parent and then update "clicks" inside the parent

Comment: the `clicks / 1 + 1` is just to have integer instead of string :P